# when UITableViewCell layout and constraints get final?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a label in my TableViewCell and I will set it's text throw a variable in cell (for example myText), like this:

```
class ProjectManagementTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    var myText: String? {
        didSet {
            if let _myText = self.myText {
                self.myLabel.text = _myText
            } else {
                self.myLabel.text = ""
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

I didn't fixed myLabel width size in InterfaceBuilder, so I expect it get resize according to text it gets from cellForRowAt function. everything good till now. but I want label width to be less than some value, and beside this, I have an image that I want to be 10 pt distance from end of text of label. so I need to have access to label width or position of UIElements after they get repositioned in response to assigning text to label. I tried several locations to find when I can access new values for frame positions, but I failed, like awakeFromNib and didSet of myText. so when I can access to final values of frames and constraints in UITableViewCell?

Comment: You can set frames in `layoutSubViews()`, but you'll be much better off using constraints and auto-layout.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need

```
var myText: String? {
    didSet {
        if let _myText = self.myText {
            self.myLabel.text = _myText
        } else {
            self.myLabel.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

just assign the text inside

```
let cell = //
cell.lbl.text = "text_here"
```

or create a configure function inside the custom cell class and call it

the label will resize according to the  the current constraints

also final frames inside

```
override func layoutSubviews()
   super.layoutSubviews()
}
```